# Fechas con LocalDate

Tags: java

Necesito ingresar una fecha mediante la consola de comandos con este formato: **`dd/mm/aa`** ej: **`15/9/2005`**

Las cosas que puedo usar son la libreria `Scanner` Y `LocalDate`

Como hago para poner la fecha en el cmd en este estilo: **`15/9/2005`** después leerlo con el `scanner` usando `.nextLine()` y después pasarlo a un `LocalDate`, actualmente estoy ingresando primero el día, doy **`ENTER`**, después el mes, doy **`ENTER`** y después el año, leo eso con **`.nextInt()`** y después pongo esas variables en **`LocalDate nacimiento = LocalDate.of(yr,m,d);`** pero quiero poner toda la fecha de corrido sin necesidad de dar mas **`ENTER's`** en la consola

Actualmente estoy haciendo esto:

```
            int d;//dia
            int m;//mes
            int yr;//anio

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Ingrese el dia");
            d = in.nextInt();
            while( d<1 || d>31){//evita que el usuario ingrese una fecha no valida
            System.out.println("Por favor ingrese una fecha valida");
            d = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");
            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Ingrese el mes");
            m = in.nextInt();
            while( m<1 || m>12){//evita que el usuario ingrese una fecha no valida
            System.out.println("Por favor ingrese una fecha valida");
            m = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");
            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Ingrese el anio");
            yr = in.nextInt();


            System.out.println("");
            LocalDate nacimiento = LocalDate.of(yr,m,d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo siguiente hace uso del paquete `java.time` que ya viene en la versión 8 de Java.

### Desarrollo

Si deseas recibir la fecha completa y pasarla a `LocalDate` primero debes de cambiar el método `nextInt()` por `next()` con la finalidad de extraer una cadena de texto:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String date = in.next();
```

Después puedes crear un método que te permita leer la cadena de texto ingresada y verificar que sea una cadena válida con el formato que deseas. Podrías lograrlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public static LocalDate stringToLocalDate(String date) {
    final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy");
    LocalDate localDate;
    try {
        localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return localDate;
}
```

En este caso se opta por utilizar la el método `DateTimeFormatter.parse` con el patrón `d/M/yyyy`.

Debido a que el método `parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter)` puede arrojar un excepción de tipo `DateTimeParseException` se opta por encerrarlo en un bloque `try / catch` para capturar la excepción y tener un valor con que verificar si todo salió correcto. En este caso si regresa una instancia de `LocalDate` significa que realizo la conversión correctamente y en caso de retornar `null` hubo un error.

Para forzar a que se ingrese una fecha válida podrías utilizar lo siguiente:

```
while (stringToLocalDate(dateRequest) == null) {
    dateRequest = in.next();
}
LocalDate date = stringToLocalDate(dateRequest);
```

### Tests

Por último, cree unas cuantas pruebas básicas para que puedas ver con distintas entradas los diversos resultados.

```
@Test
public void testLocalDate() {
    assertEquals(LocalDate.parse("2005-09-15"), UtilLocalDate.stringToLocalDate("15/9/2005"));
    assertEquals(LocalDate.parse("1990-10-12"), UtilLocalDate.stringToLocalDate("12/10/1990"));
    assertEquals(LocalDate.parse("1990-01-01"), UtilLocalDate.stringToLocalDate("1/1/1990"));
    assertEquals(LocalDate.parse("1990-01-09"), UtilLocalDate.stringToLocalDate("9/1/1990"));
    assertEquals(LocalDate.parse("1990-01-10"), UtilLocalDate.stringToLocalDate("10/1/1990"));
    assertEquals(LocalDate.parse("1990-02-28"), UtilLocalDate.stringToLocalDate("31/2/1990"));
    assertNull(UtilLocalDate.stringToLocalDate("99/99/9999"));
    assertNull(UtilLocalDate.stringToLocalDate("/2/1991"));
}
```

Las anteriores pruebas se ejecutan con éxito.

### Referencias

- [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
- [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)
- [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
- [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo concatenando las tres variables de texto donde ingresan la fecha con ese `String` puedes

Desde Java 1.8, puede lograr esto sin una biblioteca adicional utilizando las clases java.time. Ver [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
String fechaConcatenada = d +'/'+m+'/'yr;
final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
final LocalDate dt = dtf.parseLocalDate(fechaConcatenada);
```